# private network harbor access remote server using router

Tags: docker, harbor

I have harbor git registry in private network.
This network connect internet using router.

I try docker login where remote server. This server not in private network
(Remote server - Router - Harbor(Server) )

I receive error message

```
Error response from daemon: Get "https://harbor-host-name:{port}/v2/": Get "https://192.168.x.x:{port}/service/token?account={harbor-id}&client_id=docker&offline_token=true&service=harbor-registry": dial tcp 192.168.100.102:8088: connect: no route to host
```

What should i do this situation?

Another remote server in private network can login successfully.

Answer (score 0):

Solved.

vim harbor.yml
`external_url: https://harbor-host-name:{port}`

Good Luck!!!